# ¿Cómo se puede embeber un video de YouTube en el sitio?

Tags: soporte, formato

¿Cómo puedo embeber un video de YouTube en una publicación?

Ví [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/408313/abrir-formulario-desde-otro-y-que-funcione-el-codigo) que tenía un enlace a un video así:

```
[Video Error][1]
[1]: https://youtu.be/m_vp-C3qLx0
```

Y como se me hizo relevante pensé que tal vez sería buena idea que el vídeo se mostrara en la pregunta en vez de tener que salir para verlo.

Intenté generando un iframe así:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m_vp-C3qLx0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>Iframe no carga</iframe>
```

Pero la renderización es:

Iframe no carga

¿Qué sugieren al respecto?

Answer (score 2):

Lo estás haciendo bien, pero el problema es que Stack Overflow en español no tiene habilitada la función de embeber vídeos.

Puedes ver la lista completa de sitios en [Which sites have YouTube embedding on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297500/209901).

Como referencia, puedes leer sobre [muchas maneras de embeber un vídeo en Stack Exchange](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3927/4078)... en los sitios que lo permiten, claro. La más simple es poner una referencia al vídeo directamente, sin más.